# How can I set the UINavigationbar with gradient color?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, core-graphics

I want to set the `UINavigationbar` `backgroundColor` to a gradient color where I would like to set it via an array of colors to create a Gradient, ideally, as accessible methods inside `UINavigationBar` to change its color to this gradient.

Any suggestions? (Aside from setting an image manually as the background image of the navigation bar)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create gradient layer and add it as background of navigation bar.

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromLayer:gradient] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For creating image from layer.

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

One more thing, there is one library available in github : [CRGradientNavigationBar](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar) you can also use this library.

Answer (score 79):

### Details

- Xcode 11.4 (11E146), swift 5
- Tested on iOS 13.1, 12.2, 11.0.1

### Solution

```
class UINavigationBarGradientView: UIView {

    enum Point {
        case topRight, topLeft
        case bottomRight, bottomLeft
        case custom(point: CGPoint)

        var point: CGPoint {
            switch self {
                case .topRight: return CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
                case .topLeft: return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                case .bottomRight: return CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
                case .bottomLeft: return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
                case .custom(let point): return point
            }
        }
    }

    private weak var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!

    convenience init(colors: [UIColor], startPoint: Point = .topLeft,
                     endPoint: Point = .bottomLeft, locations: [NSNumber] = [0, 1]) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = frame
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        self.gradientLayer = gradientLayer
        set(colors: colors, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, locations: locations)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func set(colors: [UIColor], startPoint: Point = .topLeft,
             endPoint: Point = .bottomLeft, locations: [NSNumber] = [0, 1]) {
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint.point
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint.point
        gradientLayer.locations = locations
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        guard let parentView = superview else { return }
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        parentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard let gradientLayer = gradientLayer else { return }
        gradientLayer.frame = frame
        superview?.addSubview(self)
    }
}

extension UINavigationBar {
    func setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor],
                               startPoint: UINavigationBarGradientView.Point = .topLeft,
                               endPoint: UINavigationBarGradientView.Point = .bottomLeft,
                               locations: [NSNumber] = [0, 1]) {
        guard let backgroundView = value(forKey: "backgroundView") as? UIView else { return }
        guard let gradientView = backgroundView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UINavigationBarGradientView }) as? UINavigationBarGradientView else {
            let gradientView = UINavigationBarGradientView(colors: colors, startPoint: startPoint,
                                                           endPoint: endPoint, locations: locations)
            backgroundView.addSubview(gradientView)
            gradientView.setupConstraints()
            return
        }
        gradientView.set(colors: colors, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, locations: locations)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
navigationBar.setGradientBackground(colors: [.lightGray, .red], startPoint: .topLeft, endPoint: .bottomRight)
```

Comment: You can improve your `UINavigationBar extension` to `updatedFrame.size.height += self.frame.origin.y` to match even the new iPhone X.

Comment: Updated. Thank you!

Comment: `.setBackgroundImage(, for: )` does not work properly on iOS SDK 11, especially with search bar embedded in navigation bar. You can use `barTintColor` property instead. Basically set it using `UIColor(patternImage:)` where pattern image is your gradient.

Comment: @rafalkitta Can you set the `barTintColor` using the appearance class, or must it be done on the `UIViewController`?

Comment: I can't understand your question. In my sample there is no `barTintColor`. You want to set gradient in UIAppearance?

Comment: For left to right gradient change `endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)` to `endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)`

Comment: This made the default back button unclickable for me. To make the back button clickable again add `gradientView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` inside the `guard` statement

Comment: Thank you @PeterTao. But The problem was not about `isUserInteractionEnabled`. I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick change @VasilyBodnarchuk! 1 more small thing - I think `gradientView` should be set to `UINavigationBarGradientView(colors: colors, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint)` to use the start and end points that were passed in

Comment: @PeterTao I can not understand your idea. Sorry, can you write more detailed comment.

Comment: Right now, inside `guard let gradientView` we have hardcoded `startPoint: .topLeft, endPoint: .bottomLeft`. But maybe its better to use the `startPoint` and `endPoint` that is passed into `setGradientView`

Comment: @PeterTao yes, you right) this is my testing code. Thank you very much! I will fix it in several hours.

Answer (score 26):

In **Swift 3**, **Swift 4** and **Swift 5**:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let sizeLength = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 2
let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 64)

gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame

gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]

UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)
```

For creating image from layer:

```
func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)

    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return outputImage!
}
```

In **Swift 2**:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let sizeLength = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height * 2
let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeLength, 64)

gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame

gradient.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]

UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradient), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

For creating image from layer:

```
func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)

    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return outputImage!
}
```

Comment: Yay. This solution worked with one adaptation for me. Since I had already configured an `UINavigationBarAppearance()` instance, and had set values on it, in order to implement this solution, I just set my `navBarAppearance` instance's `backgroundImage` property to the `UIImage` returned from his `image(layer: )` method.

Comment: @Eric33187 can you post your answer?

Answer (score 10):

This is the solution without using an intermediate `CAGradientLayer`, and just using `CoreGraphics`, in Swift 3.0.

Essentially, the method creates a `UIImage` on the fly with the gradient colors passed and sets it.

```
extension UINavigationBar
{
    /// Applies a background gradient with the given colors
    func apply(gradient colors : [UIColor]) {
        var frameAndStatusBar: CGRect = self.bounds
        frameAndStatusBar.size.height += 20 // add 20 to account for the status bar

        setBackgroundImage(UINavigationBar.gradient(size: frameAndStatusBar.size, colors: colors), for: .default)
    }

    /// Creates a gradient image with the given settings
    static func gradient(size : CGSize, colors : [UIColor]) -> UIImage?
    {
        // Turn the colors into CGColors
        let cgcolors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }

        // Begin the graphics context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0.0)

        // If no context was retrieved, then it failed
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

        // From now on, the context gets ended if any return happens
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        // Create the Coregraphics gradient
        var locations : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: cgcolors as NSArray as CFArray, locations: &locations) else { return nil }

        // Draw the gradient
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), end: CGPoint(x: size.width, y: 0.0), options: [])

        // Generate the image (the defer takes care of closing the context)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

The `defer` statement makes this so much clean than prior versions.
Be noted that `CGGradient` are available since iOS 8.0.

Also, this creates the gradient from left to right, tweaking the parameters of `drawLinearGradient` (`start` and `end`) moves the locations. This is up for your implementation.

Comment: Excellent extension

Comment: For some reason this is working only about half the time for me. Leaving and re-entering the same view sometimes it works and sometimes the navbar is just a flat color.

Comment: @Maor Most likely, you're trying to set up the image when the frame of the UINavigationBar is zero (not yet laid out), that's a weakness of this implementation.

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift 4.2**

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func setGradientBackground(colors: [Any]) {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 0.5, 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        var updatedFrame = self.bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += self.frame.origin.y
        gradient.frame = updatedFrame
        gradient.colors = colors;
        self.setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)
    }

    func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage!
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setGradientBackground(colors: [
            UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.green.cgColor,
            UIColor.blue.cgColor
            ])
```

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to apply this globally using UIAppearance?

Comment: If in your case you have common GradientBackground for navigationbar in whole app?

Comment: So in this case you can set **gradient image** directly in navigation bar.

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 5**

To make the horizontal gradient background of the navigation bar along with status bar too.. just put this code in your viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
    self.navigationItem.title = "Gradiant Back Ground"
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var updatedFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] // start color and end color
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0) // Horizontal gradient start
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0) // Horizontal gradient end
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

[image: Gradient will look like this]

output Gradient will look like this.

Comment: Hey, this is not working correctly for navigationBar with large title. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 5

- Includes status bar in gradient.
- Doesn't use an image.
- Uses transparency so content is visible through nav bar.

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func addGradient(_ toAlpha: CGFloat, _ color: UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [
            color.withAlphaComponent(toAlpha).cgColor,
            color.withAlphaComponent(toAlpha).cgColor,
            color.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
        ]
        gradient.locations = [0, 0.8, 1]
        var frame = bounds
        frame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        frame.origin.y -= UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        gradient.frame = frame
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have the problem that the back button is behind the layer after a push. Does anybody experience anything similar?

Comment: This example does not cover large title, orientation change...

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let sizeLength = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 2
let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 64)
gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame
gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)

func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Objective C solution that works on iPhone X as well:

```
- (void)addGradientToNavigationBar
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGRect gradientFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
    gradientFrame.size.height += [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    gradient.frame = gradientFrame;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorGradientUp] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorGradientDown] CGColor], nil];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromLayer:gradient] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man this work for me, and also if any one want to use clear color you can use this:

self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

Answer (score 1):

This amazing tutorial from Lawrence Tan  shows how to set a gradient using `barTintColor` and no `backgroundImage`: https://medium.com/swift2go/add-gradient-to-navigation-bar-in-swift-9284fe91fea2

## Summary

`CAGradientLayer` extension

```
extension CAGradientLayer {

    class func primaryGradient(on view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let flareRed = UIColor(displayP3Red: 241.0/255.0, green: 39.0/255.0, blue: 17.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let flareOrange = UIColor(displayP3Red: 245.0/255.0, green: 175.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        var bounds = view.bounds
        bounds.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [flareRed.cgColor, flareOrange.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        return gradient.createGradientImage(on: view)
    }

    private func createGradientImage(on view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        var gradientImage: UIImage?
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            render(in: context)
            gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return gradientImage
    }
}
```

Apply the gradient

```
guard
    let navigationController = navigationController,
    let flareGradientImage = CAGradientLayer.primaryGradient(on: navigationController.navigationBar)
    else {
        print("Error creating gradient color!")
        return
    }

navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: flareGradientImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SwiftUI we can use next code, and this is also should work with UIKit:

```
private func navigationBarAppearance() {

    let gradientColors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] // Replace with your desired gradient colors

    // Create a CAGradientLayer with the gradient colors
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1] // Change as needed for your desired gradient effect
// Comment code below and the standard direction will be from top to bottom
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)


    // Set the frame of the gradient layer to match the navigation bar's frame
    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let statusBarManager = windowScene?.statusBarManager
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: (statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0) + UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height)

    // Convert the gradient layer to a UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.frame.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Set the background image of the navigation bar
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.backgroundImage = backgroundImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    
}
```

And use this in the init on View, not is the onAppear, only in the init of View or another equivalent place

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {

        navigationBarAppearance()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a framework for different UI components gradient include UINavigation bar:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/shndrs/SHNDStuffs)

first :
then in your root ViewController that it embedded into an UINavigationController

```
import SHNDStuffs
```

put this in your ViewDidLoad()

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SHNDNavigationBarGradient(firstColor: .darkGray,
                                  secondColor: .white,
                                  tintColor: .black,
                                  isHorizontal: true)
}
```