# Weird Fade On Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode

I was messing around on the IB on Xcode, and I some how got a fade on the navigation bar (take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHIFI.jpg)). The color is whiter/lighter on the top part of the navigation bar and gets darker until the bottom of the navigation bar. I don't know how to return it back to a "solid" color (i.e. remove the gradient).

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. I don't know if this issue exists when you run the project so I will cover all the bases.

Here are some suggesstions:

1. Delete the *Navigation Controller* and embed your *View Controller* in a new Navigtaion Controller. The easiest way is to select your View Controller, go to the top navigation where you can see File, Edit, View, etc. and select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

[image: Image walkthrough]

2. In your `viewDidLoad()` you can set the colour of your navigation controller like so:

`navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue`

3. In your story board, you can select the Navigation Controller scene and select the Navigation Bar and play around there, however the above 2 would be preferred.
   [image]
4. If you **want** the gradient at run time, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637829/4008175

I am making the assumption that you have not created a custom navigation bar class with an `@IBDesignable` element. I also have a feeling that when you run the project, the gradient won't be present, but since that is not mentioned, I would be ok if I am wrong.

See how these solutions work for you.

Comment: The gradient does appear in the IB and the project simulator (when built/run). So, I tried suggestion 1, and it still gave me a gradient on the navigation bar (which is very strange - it seems like it's the default behaviour). However, suggestion 2 worked for me. Thanks!