# Setting background image for a non-translucent navigation bar swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna change the background color of my navbar, while set the translucency to false, It's just plain white and it won't change untill I set an image for the background color. any help would be appreciated.

```
let homeViewController = HomeViewController();
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController);
let navBar = navigationController.navigationBar;
navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white];
navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default);
navBar.shadowImage = UIImage();
navBar.isTranslucent = false;
navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red; //not working
navBar.tintColor = UIColor.red //not working
```

*** EDIT ***

Thank you so much you guys, yea that was it, can you please help me a bit further. the reason I wanted to change the color of navbar was because I wanted to make it transparent so I could add a gradient background to it, and with barTintColor now I could set it to clear.
but still this

```
navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white];
navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default);
navBar.shadowImage = UIImage();
navBar.isTranslucent = false;
navBar.barTintColor = .clear;
```

doesn't work and I still don't see my gradient which I set like this :

```
let bg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "gradient"));
bg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.width, height: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (navBar.frame.height));
bg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill;
bg.layer.masksToBounds = true;
bg.layer.opacity = 1;
navigationController.view.insertSubview(bg, belowSubview: navBar);
```

The reason I'm not just setting the background image with `setBackgroundImage` is I wanna change the position of the background image in the navbar so it should be on the right of the navbar.

I know I got the answer to my question but this was the real one and still can't figure it out. I'm gonna mark the best answer anyway either if you guys answer me or not but I would really appreciate if you could help me further.

- EDIT *

Added Image

[image: Image of The Problem]

Comment: there should be a property name "navBar.barTintColor". please try to use this.

Comment: Do you want to have the same navigation bar look throughout your whole app?

Comment: if you got your answer please accept it.

Comment: for gradient you are using image right?

Comment: @MRizwan33 yep because it was radial and was too hard to make it in swift for me.

Comment: can't you just set this. navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "gradient"), forBarMetrics: .Default)

Comment: @MRizwan33 no as I mentioned in the question I wanna change the position of the image, to the right of my navbar. it's not gonna be center or if setting backgroundImage has any option to move the background that I don't know.

Comment: i didn't get exactly what you want can you please share image description?

Comment: @MRizwan33 yep I added the Image.

Comment: By the way. what you edited is not related with your first question. Mark this as a second question. If you got your first answer then close this one please.

Answer (score 3):

You set the wrong property.

Set `barTintColor` to apply your background color:

```
navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Here's the Apple docs: [barTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624931-bartintcolor)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna mark the answer in a short time but I edited the question could be help me further?

Comment: @ArmanMomeni, try setting like there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43637829/5147552

Comment: Because you won't be able to control the image effectively on different screen sizes, it's better to take a more reliable approach and set background like there.

Answer (score 2):

This property is for Bar Text Color.

```
navBar.tintColor
```

Use This: (for NavBar Background Color).

```
navBar.barTintColor
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna mark the answer in a short time but I edited the question could be help me further?