# Gradient Background for Navigation bar on iPhoneX

Tags: uinavigationbar, swift4, ios11, background-color, iphone-x

Gradient background is not applied for navigation bar on iPhoneX.
This is my function code:

```
    func setGradientBackground(Colors: [UIColor]) {

    var updatedFrame = bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += self.frame.origin.y

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436{
            updatedFrame.size.height += 44
        } else {
            updatedFrame.size.height += 20
        }

    }

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(frame: updatedFrame, colors: Colors)
    setBackgroundImage(gradientLayer.createGradientImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

}
```

[Here is the result for iPhoneX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0315W.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884170/how-can-i-set-the-uinavigationbar-with-gradient-color

Comment: Thank you, but this worked with all other devices except iPhoneX. That's my problem!

Comment: use `updatedFrame.size.height += navigationBar.frame.maxY` and let's me know