# Gradient color to Navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am trying to apply the gradient color to `UINavigationBar.appearence()`.  For this ,I followed the [link](https://medium.com/swift2go/add-gradient-to-navigation-bar-in-swift-9284fe91fea2). But after adding that extension of `CAGradientLayer` class,I have written the below lines of code in did finish launching with options in `APPDelegate` class. But I am getting an error like "Value of optional type `UIImage?` must be unwrapped to a value of type `UIImage`".Here am using `UINavigationbar`. Not the `Navigationcontroller`

Can anyone help me to do this, would be great.

```
// In AppDelegate Class

let navigationbar=UINavigationBar()
        let flareGradientImage = CAGradientLayer.primaryGradient(on: navigationbar)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(patternImage: flareGradientImage)



        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884170/how-can-i-set-the-uinavigationbar-with-gradient-color This link gonna help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your CAGradientLayer extension is getting bounds of navigation bar. Just initialising to UINavigationBar() won't work as its bound will be (0,0,0,0) and secondly you need to use below code to set it as backgroundImage.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(flareGradientImage, for:.default)
```

Comment: I have tried this line of code before, but it was giving white color for navigation bar

Comment: You should check for frame in your extension